# Webpage doesn't scroll smoothly on screen

Tags: html, css, optimization, twitter-bootstrap-3, pageload

I tried many optimization methods but I can't optimize my web page...

Here is an example of my webpage: https://dev.dineandgift.com/voucher/108 and as you can see it don't run smoothly so when you scroll down you will see what I'm talking about.

What is the problem on that page? It is not a big page and its based on bootstrap3.

Is there any js library that will help me to optimize this code to run smoothly?

What you suggest?

Comment: It's quite smooth for me. So not sure how to help. Using Chrome v69 on Mac OS 10.13.6. Can you verify that it's not your device? Also do you notice differences on other browsers?

Comment: yes, mobile also scroll bad and load very slow

Comment: Can you provide a list of OS + Browser combos on which you are experiencing the issue? Also, the question is off-topic without a working [mcve] inside the question itself. After you fix the issue on your dev server the question will no longer be helpful to future users with the same issue. So please, reproduce the issue in a snippet inside the question.

Comment: ok, I will post the code

Comment: Most likely, you need to save your background image at a lower resolution, but that might not be the only problem.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu what is the other problems ?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` on scrolling element if you are facing scrolling issue. Above style will make your Scroll smooth for mobile devices.